# g++ template bug or VC too liberal?

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I am writing a heavily templated piece of code in C++. It worked perfectly in VS 2005 but when I try to compile it in g++ I get some really strange errors.

The essential piece of code (simplified to a minimum, doesn't compile either) is as follows:

```
template <class Actual>
class Generic
{
public:
    typedef Actual ThisType;
};

template <class Actual>
class Intermediate : public Generic<Actual>
{
};

template <class Q>
class Derived : public Intermediate<Derived<Q> >
{
public:
    void FooBar()
    {
        ThisType q;
    }
};
```

The error is:
    "'ThisType' was not declared in this scope"
in the line where 'q' is being declared.

Curiously, everything works fine when Derived is not a template but a plain class. Why would compiler look into template function implementation before it is even instantiated? I know that VC++ checks far too little when compiling templates (unused templates can even contain syntactically incorrect code) - but isn't g++ checking too much here? I tried adding a typename keyword with little hope and it fails too. Is there any way to get ThisType to work as expected? I dread the thought of adding it manually to every single derived class - it's cumbersome, redundant, inelegant and error-inducing.

Best regards,
MZ

Comment: I find it funny that `return *this;` doesn't raise any compilation errors since the function is `void`.

Comment: If you ask this question, the answer is pretty much always "VC is too liberal".

Comment: I admit when I look at this code my brain gets parse errors too

Answer (score 4):

Unqualified names are not looked up in dependent base classes (your base class depends on template parameter `Q`). Qualify that name, and it will work.

```
typename Derived::ThisType q;
```

Comment: I don't want to qualify - I'd rather redefine ThisType in the derived class... And it was so simple with VC.

Comment: @MichalZ it's simple with GCC too. I see no reason `typedef typename Intermediate<Derived<Q> >::ThisType ThisType;` within the derived class shouldn't work.

Comment: Well, it does. But it's not the point. The code relies heavily on symbols defined in base classes. The end-stage classes are always templates because that is the whole idea behind the code. There are things other than types used in this manner and there are no workarounds as simple as a typedef in the derived class. The whole library became generally unusable - the process of making the code standard-conformant will turn it into some nightmarish spaghetti. I know that VC++ has standards of its own, but in this case it is simply FAR better that it doesn't follow ISO :(

Comment: Gee... I got it to work (took 2 hours) but the code is horribly mutilated. this-> all over the place along with redeclaring the same typedef over and over again... It's standard compliant now, but ugly.

Comment: @curiousguy you can do that too, but the C++03 spec lacked some rules to make `ThisType q;` work then (it missed to specify that `ThisType` will be a type name). C++11 clarified the rules, but wide spread GCC versions (at least up to 4.3) don't implement the clarified rules and will reject `ThisType q;`, despite the using declaration you put.

Answer (score 1):

Trust in [Comeau online compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/)!

```
Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008 11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing.  All rights reserved.
MODE:strict errors C++ C++0x_extensions

"ComeauTest.c", line 19: error: identifier "ThisType" is undefined
          ThisType q;
          ^

"ComeauTest.c", line 19: error: expected a ";" (perhaps on the previous statement)
          ThisType q;
                   ^

2 errors detected in the compilation of "ComeauTest.c".
```

Dependent type names from inherited classes are not taken into account, you might try to explicitly request ThisType:

```
typename Intermediate<Derived<Q> >::ThisType q;
```

Comment: Last error is quite obvious - I simplified the code and that 'return' survived the process. Still, it does not help much. The code won't compile. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a **typename**

```
template <class Actual> class Generic { public:
    typedef Actual ThisType; };

template <class Actual> class Intermediate : public Generic<Actual> { };

template <class Q> class Derived : public Intermediate<Derived<Q> > { public:
    void FooBar()
    {
        typename Derived::ThisType q;
        return *this;
    } };

int main(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is indeed ill-formed. When base class depends on template parameter it is not considered by name lookup when looking for unqualified names.

In your case unqualified name `ThisType` will not be looked up in base class `Intermediate<Derived<Q> >` because your base class depends on template parameter `Q`.